# Android App works well in Api 21 & 23 but RuntimeException in 19?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I have an app with `minimum sdk - 14` and `target sdk - 23`.
My app works well on `API` `21` & `23` but facing an `RuntimeException` on `19`.
This is the error-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiateapplication com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.blogspot.appsjango.App-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-l
ib/com.appsjango.App-1, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
```

I have seen some answers for similar questions answering disable `instant run` but app is in apk and runs in some devices. So it is not an actual solution.

Comment: "So it is not an actual solution" -- it certainly could be. Have you tried it?

Comment: But app works in other devices.

Comment: So? That does not prevent some Instant Run-related problem on this particular device, based on Android OS version or something.

Comment: ok. let me check. i will get back.

Comment: Thank. Instant run is a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare says the Instant run makes the problem.
 When i turn off the instant run it runs fine.
 I also notify that the size of App reduce when the Instant Run turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Instant Run need to add some files related to the API when building the apk. So, if you need to build the app with Instant Run turn on, you must provided the related API SDK.

For example, if you want the app run in API Level 19, then you need to download API Level 19 to your Android SDK.